# How come my image is not displayed in the pop up window?

Tags: javascript, html, coldfusion, coldfusion-9, coldfusion-10

I'm a newbie to ColdFushion.  I'm trying to create a page where user can view small pictures.  Once he clicks on a picture, another image will show up in a new pop up window.  I'm not sure what's missing in my code, but when I click on the small picture, a new window will pop up..There's no image in the new pop up window even I set the image path.  Can someone give me some suggestions on how to fix this?  Thanks a lot!

EDIT: I followed the suggestion and made some changes to my code.  However, it is still not working.  Can someone tell me what I'm missing?  Thanks!

In full_article_view.cfm:

```
<!--- retrieve the full article as well as its images --->
<CFQUERY NAME="myQuery1" Datasource="mydb" >
SELECT articles.article_ID, articles.article_title, articles.article_author,    
    articles.article_date, articles.article_content
FROM articles
INNER JOIN article_image_mapping ON articles.article_ID = 
    article_image_mapping.aim_articleID
WHERE articles.article_ID = #URL.ID#
GROUP BY article_image_mapping.aim_articleID
</CFQUERY>

<CFQUERY NAME="myQuery2" Datasource="mydb" >
SELECT images.image_ID, images.image_thumbpath, images.image_fullpath
FROM images
INNER JOIN article_image_mapping ON images.image_ID = article_image_mapping.aim_imageID
WHERE article_image_mapping.aim_articleID = #URL.ID#
</CFQUERY>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Hi</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
    <!--- Page Title --->
    <h3>Full Article View</h3>

    <!--- Page Content --->
    <div align="left">
        <!--- Display article title, author, date, and full content --->
        <cfoutput query="myQuery1">
            <b>#ucase(myquery1.article_title)#</b>
            <hr>
            <p style="color:##848181; font-size:12px">#myquery1.article_author#    
                            :: #myquery1.article_date#</p>
            #myquery1.article_content#<br/>
        </cfoutput>
        <br>
        <!--- Display images associated with article--->
        <cfoutput query= "myQuery2">

            <img src="#myquery2.image_thumbpath#" alt="image thumbnail"
            onClick="ColdFusion.Window.create('Window1', 'This is a CF window',
            'full_img.cfm?toshow=#myquery2.image_fullpath#',
            {x:100,y:100,height:300,width:400,modal:false,closable:true,
            draggable:true,resizable:true,center:true,initshow:true,
            minheight:200,minwidth:200})">

        </cfoutput>


    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

In full_img.cfm:

```
<cfparam name="url.toshow" default="">

<cfoutput>
<img src="#url.toshow#" alt="full image">
</cfoutput>
```

Comment: First things first: get rid of the `<cfwindow>`: https://github.com/cfjedimaster/ColdFusion-UI-the-Right-Way/blob/master/chapters/cfwindow/index.md

Comment: First things first: fix the SQL injection! Then correct the doctype to `<!doctype html>`. _Then_ get rid of the cfwindow use. (And if at that point there's still an issue, update the question with the new code.)

Comment: While we are at it.....get rid of the `SELECT * FROM`. Instead, list out only the columns you need (and even if you need all of them....list them out).

Comment: Just to camp on to @Scotts's comment, using `SELECT * FROM` is generally a bad idea for various reasons, but especially in queries with any kind of join.  If any 2 tables in such a query have columns with identical names, the database may throw an error, or may prefix just those columns with the table names, making them a little harder to access in your code.  Also, if you alter any of the tables used in the query by adding or removing columns, you may get unexpected results if you use ColdFusion's query caching features.

Answer (score 2):

The reason it fails is because cfwindow expects the URL loaded to return text, not binary data. When you said the third arg to ColdFusion.Window.create was the image source, you essentially tried to load binary image data into the window contents, which will not work.

There is a simple enough workaround. Build a new CFM called, well, whatever you want, with code like so:

```
<cfparam name="url.toshow" default="">
<cfoutput>
<img src="#url.toshow#">
</cfoutput>
```

This CFM just takes in a URL parameter for an image and renders the HTML to load it. Then modify your original code to use this new url:

```
onClick="ColdFusion.Window.create('Window1', 'This is a CF window',
'test3.cfm?toshow=#urlencodedformat(iurl)#',
```

In my example above, test3.cfm was my test file.

And yes - stop using CF UI stuff too. ;)

Comment: Thanks so much for the suggestions. I'm really new to this.  I'm not sure if I fully understand your code.  I made some changes to mine, but it's still not working.  Do you mind to take a look and let me know what I'm missing?  Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: What goes wrong? How about you also add the output, ie above the img src, just output the value of url.toshow.

Comment: I think the "on click" is not working in <img src>.  When I click on an image, it does not open a new window.  I tried to test it a google url.    <cfoutput query= "myQuery2"><img src="#myquery2.image_thumbpath#" alt="image thumbnail" onClick="ColdFusion.Window.create('Window1', 'This is a CF window', 'http://www.google.com' {x:100,y:100,height:300,width:400,modal:false,closable:true, draggable:true,resizable:true,center:true,initshow:true, minheight:200,minwidth:200})"></cfoutput>

Comment: No, Sorry. It did not work.  I am still stuck.  When I click on the image, nothing shows. =(

Comment: Ok, can you show us the URL on a live server? Oh - wait - you used a semicolon after the url I think - switch it to a comma.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help!  I ended up using javascript and solved my problem. =)